# After deploying my site to Github pages, the URL has a serious problem I'm not sure how to fix

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

SEE UPDATE!!

I have tried to deploy my ReactJS page to Github, and the followed the rules to a tee.

Both from: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment
and
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/surge-vs-github-pages-deploying-a-create-react-app-project-c0ecbf317089

The error I get when doing the second, after many attempts at the first, is:

```
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error
```

what could be going on?

**EDIT**: ok now I have a site up, but the URL is myname.github.io/myname.github.io . How can I fix this?

Comment: can you add what rules/instructions you use?

Comment: @mfakhrusy done and done

Comment: why not doing the first one? The first one from official CRA docs should do the trick. And on which step you encountered that error?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment have you seen the "Troubleshooting" section from this documentation?

Answer (score 0):

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#troubleshooting

taken from here:

try adding a new Personal Access Token:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<user>:<token>@github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

.
Try npm run deploy again

======= edit after seeing the addition on the original question.

So I thought it's a project page... But it's a github.io page. In that case, just push your app to master (the build/dist folder), move everything else (the source especially) to other branch if you want to clean up in master branch. More info: https://pages.github.com/

What you encountered `https://yourname.github.io/yourproject` is a project page, so if you're building a project, you can automatically add it into your main github page (your github.io).

Comment: how about just build your page and push on gh-pages branch manually? You can achieve that without much hassle actually @user11039951

Comment: actually now I have a page up, but it's URL is myname.github.io/myname.github.io